# Which is better Await Vs Then for NodeJs Promise? and How Await works

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, asynchronous, async-await

Hi I just started nodejs, I read some articles for async functions. There are some something really confused me, I hope to get some explanation or recommended materials here.

1. I know in async function, we can resolve a promise using then, also we can use 'await' to wait for promise resolved. Which is better? or are they same mechanism?
2. Actually, I use multiple await in my nodejs async function, for my understanding, await will stop the script and wait. This is sound like a synchronous function, right? So why do we need await? Is this a good way to do coding in Node?
3. I call these async functions in angularJS(using promise.then()) to get result. How does it works? I mean, what will I happened when angular call node function, how do them communicate?

If any unclear please comment.
Thank you so much

Comment: They're interoperable, async/await is just syntactic sugar for promises.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, as a technicality, if you read up on the mdn docs, they are different, but functionally they work in similar ways

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An `async function`, always return a pending Promise that will be resolved with the value returned by the function (so the function runs asynchronously)

Using `await`, the current function is suspended until the promise associated with the `await` is resolved (so the javascript below an `await` is transformed to a `then()` of the awaited promise)

Using `then()`, you stay in the function after declaring the promise, meaning that you can start multiple promises in parallel.

`await` is interesting because it simplifies the code when you have to wait for the result before continuing the function, like using a `then` for rest of the function.

Because `await` suspends the code, everything below an `await` is deferred, including any new promise.
So if you want to start all the promises in backgound, you must declare and store them into variables before using any `await`, like this:

```
var p1 = new Promise(...)
var p2 = new Promise(...)
try {
  let r1 = await p1;
  let r2 = await p2;
} catch (e) {}
```

Comment: do you mean using await, i cannot start multiple promises in parallel?

Comment: what do you mean interesting when I have to wait?

Comment: I changed my answer. Is that clearer?

Comment: As a more concise alternative for awaiting multiple promises, you can use `await Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(([r1, r2]) => {});`